# Scrolling page indicator in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a PageView containing a large number of pages. I am using [smooth_page_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/smooth_page_indicator) to indicate the current page. The problem is that since I have a large number of pages, some of the dots are off-screen. I need them to scroll when necessary, and for that I found [scrolling_page_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/scrolling_page_indicator) package, but it has not been updated for a long time.
Is there any other package similar to this?

Answer (score 0):

I modified the source code of that package and it runs perfectly fine. It wasn't that difficult since whole package contains 207 lines of code. I would like to share it with everyone, but I don't know if it would violate copyrights or whatever. If someone confirms that it would be fine with copyrights, I would be more than happy to share.

Comment: Hi erhan :) it's open source. you can pull request and contribute to project. [repo](https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/smooth_page_indicator). [How to pull request](https://github.com/firstcontributions/first-contributions)